# Sync queue between two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This is a simple program which has a function start() which waits for user to enter something(using infinite loop) and stores it in queue. start() runs in a separate thread. After user enters some value, the size of queue remains zero in main. How can the queue be synchronized?

code: source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "kl.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(start);
    while (1)
    {
        if (q.size() > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "never gets inside this if\n";
            std::string first = q.front();
            q.pop();
        }           
    }
    t1.join();
}
```

code: kl.h

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>

void start();
static std::queue<std::string> q;
```

code: kl.cpp

```
#include "kl.h"
using namespace std;

void start()
{
    char i;
    string str;
    while (1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            //other stuff and str input
            q.push(str);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: added full code

Comment: Because you use 'static' on the queue in the header file, you actually have 2 different queues, one in each cpp file.  That's why the one in main is always empty.

Comment: @tony It shows linker errors on removing static.

Comment: Yep, I suspect it does.  Try extern.  And then `std::queue<std::string> q;` in main.cpp.  The h file says "this thing exists, somewhere", the cpp file says "it is here".  Better yet, make it static in main, _remove_ it from the header, and pass it by reference into the thread function.

Comment: @tony Thanks! this one worked too

Comment: boost has a synchronized queue at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html#thread.sds.synchronized_queues .  there is also a lock-free queue in boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a [race](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) - by me it crashed; both threads are potentially modifying a shared queue. (Also, you're looping with `char i` for values up to 1000 - not a good idea, probably.)

You should protect your shared queue with a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), and use a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to notify that there is a reason to check the queue.

Specifically, you should consider the following (which is very common for your case of [a producer consumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)):

1. Access the queue only when holding the mutex.
2. Use the condition variable to notify that you've pushed something into it.
3. Use the condition variable to specify a condition on when there's a point to continue processing.

Here is a rewrite of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

std::queue<std::string> q;
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;

void start()
{
    string str;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        //other stuff and str input
        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        q.push(str);
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(start);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return !q.empty();});
        std::string first = q.front();
        q.pop();    
    }
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: @ami-travory could you elaborate on what this line is doing and the sintax?
`cv.wait(lk, []{return !q.empty();});`

Answer (score 0):

My synced queue class example and its usage:

```
template<typename T>
class SyncQueue
{
    std::queue<T> m_Que;
    std::mutex m_Lock;
    std::condition_variable m_ConVar;

public:
    void enque(T item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Lock);
        m_Que.push(item);
        lock.unlock();
        m_ConVar.notify_all();
    }

    T deque()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_Lock);

        do
        {
            m_ConVar.wait(lock);

        } while(m_Que.size() == 0); // extra check from spontaneous notifications

        auto ret = m_Que.front();
        m_Que.pop();

        return ret;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    SyncQueue<int> sq;

    std::thread consumer([&sq]()
    {
        std::cout << "consumer" << std::endl;

        for(;;)
        {
            std::cout << sq.deque() << std::endl;
        }
    });

    std::thread provider([&sq]()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        sq.enque(1);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
        sq.enque(2);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
        sq.enque(3);
    });

    consumer.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /*  Here I have a code snippate with Separate class for 
>     Producing and Consuming along with buffer class */
>
>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <mutex>
> #include <condition_variable>
> #include <thread>
> #include <deque>
> #include <vector>
> using namespace std;
> mutex _mutex_1,_mutex_2;
> condition_variable cv;
>
> template <typename T>
> class Queue
> {
>     deque<T> _buffer;
>     const unsigned int max_size = 10;
> public:
>     Queue() = default;
>     void push(const T& item)
>     {
>         while(1)
>         {
>             unique_lock<mutex> locker(_mutex_1);
>             cv.wait(locker,[this](){ return _buffer.size() < max_size; });
>             _buffer.push_back(item);
>             locker.unlock();
>             cv.notify_all();
>             return;
>         }
>     }
>
>     T pop()
>     {
>         while(1)
>         {
>             unique_lock<mutex> locker(_mutex_1);
>             cv.wait(locker,[this](){ return _buffer.size() > 0; });
>             int back = _buffer.back();
>             _buffer.pop_back();
>             locker.unlock();
>             cv.notify_all();
>             return back;
>         }
>     }
> };
>
>
>
> class Producer
> {
>     Queue<int>* _buffer;
>
> public:
>     Producer(Queue<int>* _buf)
>     {
>         this->_buffer = _buf;
>     }
>     void run()
>     {
>         while(1)
>         {
>             auto num = rand()%100;
>             _buffer->push(num);
>             _mutex_2.lock();
>             cout<<"Produced:"<<num<<endl;
>             this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
>             _mutex_2.unlock();
>         }
>     }
> };
>
>
> class Consumer
> {
>     Queue<int>* _buffer;
>
> public:
>     Consumer(Queue<int>* _buf)
>     {
>         this->_buffer = _buf;
>     }
>     void run()
>     {
>         while(1)
>         {
>             auto num = _buffer->pop();
>             _mutex_2.lock();
>             cout<<"Consumed:"<<num<<endl;
>             this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(50));
>             _mutex_2.unlock();
>         }
>     }
> };
>
>
>
> void client()
> {
>
>     Queue<int> b;
>     Producer p(&b);
>     Consumer c(&b);
>     thread producer_thread(&Producer::run, &p);
>     thread consumer_thread(&Consumer::run, &c);
>     producer_thread.join();
>     consumer_thread.join();
> }
>
>
> int main()
> {
>     client();
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```